# How to enable text drag-and-drop in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: linux, sublime-text-2, drag-and-drop

I'm on Ubuntu 12 and the drag-and-drop feature of Sublime Text 2 refuses to work even though it is explicitly enabled in the configuration file:

> "drag_text": true

and isn't overridden anywhere else. The lack of drag-and-drop really slows down productivity for me so I even tried installing Windows version of Sublime Text on Wine as a workaround but it doesn't even launch from Wine.

Comment: Sublime Text, Build 3047 (ST3 !) on Kubuntu 13.04 no any drag-and-drop  support. Ridiculous.

Comment: It is implemented ST, but not for Linux. Tested in ST3 Build 3143 in mac. Comment in drag_text setting: "When drag_text is enabled, clicking on selected text will begin a drag-drop operation. This is not currently implemented under Linux."

Answer (score 1):

From this post on the sublime text forum, there's no support for drag & drop text on Linux systems.
https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5785

Comment: "Added text drag and drop" is a change in version 2.0 from June 26th though.

Comment: No, not added. I use 3047 on Kubuntu 13.04 and it doesn't have drag-and-drop. It is ridiculous, one of the most used features and isn't provided.

Answer (score 0):

I too missed drap & drop not existing for Sublime in Linux as I really like it in Windows. However, if you highlight what you want to drap & drop, then *middle click* where you want that highlighted text to go, the original highlighting is still there, and you can just hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> - a move has been accomplished.

At first, it seemed like a compromise to drag & drop, but as I got used to it, I found that it had much more utility, and was just as fast or even faster depending on what I was doing.

For example, once what you want to drag & drop is highlighted, you can middle click in many places rapidly, and the highlighted text is copied multiple times. No need to repeatedly drag & drop.

In summary, you get used to it, it's actually very good, and many times it's even faster and easier.